# Vuejs router after deployment and nodejs backend

Tags: node.js, vuejs2, deployment, hosting

I am using Vue2 with nodejs. After making npm run build and deploying to host, the router links are giving 404.

My vue.config.js:

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service');
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: ['vuetify'],
});
```

and my index.js (showing only one path otherwise its too long):

```js
{
    path: '/AddPosts',
    name: 'AddPostsView',
    component: () => import('./../views/AddPostsView.vue'),
  },
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes,
});

export default router;
```

When loaded to firebase there is a way to choose "single page application" then the routes worked fine. But how can i change in my app so it uses only my index.html. Hosting it to site where I upload it with FTP.

I have tried change the history mode but nothing: [https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#html5-mode](https://www.stackoverflow.com/).

I also tried vue.config.js this:

```js
publicPath: '/'
```

How can I get my routes to work so it won't give me 404 when I go to the next page?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add ".htaccess" file to the HOST server via FTP or as they call it in vue doc. [page](https://v3.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations)  APACHE. Content of the file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>   
  RewriteEngine On   RewriteBase /  
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d   RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```